# Using JavaScript to produce defined number of divs

Tags: javascript, html

So i have been trying to tackle this problem for the past few hours and it has really stumped me, as far as i can see everything is correct. The create function is meant to create a specific amount of divs that are defined by the user within an input box. The divs will have a specific height, width values however they will have a random colour assigned to them. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
James!

Comment: well you are missing a closing bracket for your `create` function

Comment: I added the bracket, the divs then appear for a split second and disappear? can't believe I missed bracket though

Comment: the form is submitting, I would just ditch the form and select your input via id. You could also stop the event from firing

Comment: @JamesDean: Why on earth would you try to delete the code solution I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, there are two erroneous things

- There is syntax error in your code. `function create()` is missing a `}`.
- Add a `type="button"` attribute on your button in order to stop the form getting submitted. You can also use `event.preventDefault()`

```js
function create() {
  var form = document.getElementById("boxForm");
  noBoxes = form.elements["noBox"].value;

  for (var i = 0; i < noBoxes; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.color = "";
    div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    div.style.height = "50px";
    div.style.width = "50px";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  var color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<form id="boxForm">
  <input type="text" name="noBox">
  <button type="button" onclick="create();">Enter</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing brace, and need to prevent the form submission.

```js
function create(event) {
  // The event object is passed in so you can prevent the form submission
  event.preventDefault(); 

  var form = document.getElementById("boxForm");
  noBoxes = form.elements["noBox"].value;

  for (var i = 0; i < noBoxes; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.color = "";
    div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    div.style.height = "50px";
    div.style.width = "50px";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var color = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="boxForm">
  <input value=4 type="text" name="noBox">
  <button onclick="create(event)">Enter</button>
</form>
```